# Octopress Blog Post URL remove hyphens

Tags: octopress

I would like to replace the hyphens of the blog post permalink to something else (perhaps use periods or remove the spaces all together).

I've combed through the code, but couldn't find where the magic happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the date part, it should be in plugins/date.rb. Look for `slug` method. For the rest of the title, I'm afraid you have to look in Jekyll's sources.